# merge 2 lists into a new list that contains both data from list 1 and list 2 - where the unique key is "VariantId"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two lists of data (they are using the same class "SaleNumber").

Each list contains a list of sale numbers. The first list is taken from the danish "DK" database and the other from the swedish database.

Right now I am looping through the danish list For each item I loop through I find the item with the same variant id in the swedish list and then I join the data into a new list called saleNumbers.

The problem with this is that because I loop through the danish list then if the danish list doesn't have salenumbers for that variant id then it won't loop through this variant. If this happens then the swedish list item won't be added either - and therefore the salenumbers item won't be created - even though it should - it should have a 0 in salenumbers.totalsalesDK and the actual salenumber for the salenumbers.totalsalesSE.

How do I merge the two together into salenumbers without missing any variants?

I still want the structure retained - so that for instance I have the SaleNumbers.TotalSales showing sum of totalsales for both dk and se together. And the SaleNumbers.TotalSalesDK showing DK sales and SaleNumbers.TotalSalesSE showing SE sales for that item. The primary unique key is always the variantId.  Here is my current code:

```
    private List<SaleNumber> ConvertDataTableToSaleNumbers(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<SaleNumber> saleNumbers = new List<SaleNumber>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            saleNumbers.Add(new SaleNumber() { ProductId = int.Parse(dr["productid"].ToString()), TotalSales = int.Parse(dr["totalsales"].ToString()), VariantId = int.Parse(dr["variantid"].ToString()) });
        }
        return saleNumbers;
    }  

 DataTable dtDK = new Shoply.Data.DLOrderDetail().GetNumberOfSalesSinceOrderId(constDaysAgo, 
 Shoply.Data.DLBasis.GetTheConnectionToTheLanguage("dk"));
        DataTable dtSE = new Shoply.Data.DLOrderDetail().GetNumberOfSalesSinceOrderId(constDaysAgo, 
 Shoply.Data.DLBasis.GetTheConnectionToTheLanguage("se"));         

        List<SaleNumber> saleNumbersDK = ConvertDataTableToSaleNumbers(dtDK);
        List<SaleNumber> saleNumbersSE = ConvertDataTableToSaleNumbers(dtSE);

        var saleNumbers = saleNumbersDK.SelectMany
          (
              foo => saleNumbersSE.Where(bar => foo.VariantId == bar.VariantId).DefaultIfEmpty(),
              (foo, bar) => new SaleNumber
              {
                  VariantId = foo.VariantId,
                  ProductId = foo.ProductId,
                  TotalSales = foo.TotalSales + (bar == null ? 0 : bar.TotalSales),
                  TotalSalesDK = foo.TotalSales,
                  TotalSalesSE = (bar == null ? 0 : bar.TotalSales)
              }
          );
```

Comment: Do you just want to add up the Total Sales per VariantId or do you still want to track whether it was a "DK sale" or a "SE sale"? Also, what does your SaleNumber class look like? Can you add it?

Answer (score 3):

*EDIT:*
Code updated to perform outerjoin

---

How about using [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8) in Linq.

Simple dotnetfiddle can be seen here : [Dotnetfiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoAFvN)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SaleNumber> saleNumbersDK = new List<SaleNumber> {
                new SaleNumber() { VariantId="a",ProductId="A",TotalSales=10 },
                new SaleNumber() { VariantId="b",ProductId="B",TotalSales=20 }

            };
            List<SaleNumber> saleNumbersSE = new List<SaleNumber> {
                new SaleNumber() { VariantId="a",ProductId="A",TotalSales=10 },
                new SaleNumber() { VariantId="c",ProductId="c",TotalSales=30 }

            };

            var innerjoin = saleNumbersDK.Join(saleNumbersSE, d => d.VariantId, s => s.VariantId, (d, s) =>
            {
                return new SaleNumber()
                {
                    VariantId = d.VariantId,
                    ProductId = d.ProductId,
                    TotalSales = d.TotalSales+ (s == null ? 0 : s.TotalSales),
                    TotalSalesDK = d.TotalSales,
                    TotalSalesSE = (d == null ? 0 : d.TotalSales)
                };
            });
            var pendingright= saleNumbersSE.Except(innerjoin, new CustomComparer());
            var pendingleft = saleNumbersDK.Except(innerjoin, new CustomComparer());
            var salesNumber= innerjoin.Concat(pendingright).Concat(pendingleft);
            foreach (var sale in salesNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sale);
            }
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }


}
public class SaleNumber
    {
        public string VariantId { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public int TotalSales { get; set; }
        public int TotalSalesDK { get; set; }
        public int TotalSalesSE { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return VariantId+"-"+ProductId+"-"+TotalSales+"-"+TotalSalesDK+"-"+TotalSalesSE;
        }
    }

public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<SaleNumber>
    {
        public bool Equals(SaleNumber x, SaleNumber y)
        {
            return x.VariantId == y.VariantId;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(SaleNumber obj)
        {
            return obj.VariantId.GetHashCode();           
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work -I have an item in saleNumbersSE - 

variantid:2085 productid:1910 totalsales:2 this item is not showing up - I guess the reason is that there is no sales on this variantId in saleNumbersDK. You can also see it in the dotnetfiddle example where b and c are not being shown as they should.

Comment: @NickDeveloper Correct join will perform inner-join , after looking at your code more closely I could see you were able to perfrom left outer join. sadly I am not aware of outer join in Linq , though you can perform left outer join using GroupJoin extenstion method. Updated code to reflect outer join. Hope this will give you some hint.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ProductId is the same for DK and SE you can use a group by function like this to get the result you want.

```
testDK.ForEach(s => s.TotalSalesDK = s.TotalSales);
testSE.ForEach(s => s.TotalSalesSE = s.TotalSales);
testDK.Concat(testSE)
   .GroupBy(s => s.VariantId)
   .Select(g => new SaleNumber() { 
      VariantId = g.First().VariantId,
      ProductId=g.First().ProductId,
      TotalSales = g.Sum(s=>s.TotalSalesDK) + g.Sum(s=>s.TotalSalesSE),
      TotalSalesDK=g.Sum(s=>s.TotalSalesDK),
      TotalSalesSE=g.Sum(s=>s.TotalSalesSE)
   }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Concat__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) and [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) methods:

```
var allProducts = productCollection1.Concat(productCollection2)
                                     .Concat(productCollection3)
                                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but I still want to retain the new structure after they have been joined:

              (foo, bar) => new SaleNumber
              {
                  VariantId = foo.VariantId,
                  ProductId = foo.ProductId,
                  TotalSales = foo.TotalSales + (bar == null ? 0 : bar.TotalSales),
                  TotalSalesDK = foo.TotalSales,
                  TotalSalesSE = (bar == null ? 0 : bar.TotalSales)
                }

For instance - the one showing totalsales for both dk and se has to be filled.